# LESS Preprocessing and null arguments?

Tags: less

This might be difficult to explain. Is there a way to have less not write out the @child argument without overloading the mix-in? I really don't want two mix-ins. If I use "" double quotes are outputted. I would like the LESS compiler to leave it blank.

**LESS CODE**

```
.build-on(size, @child) 
{
    &--1-1 @{child}
    {             
        width: 100%;
    }

    &--1-2 @{child}
    {
        width: 50.0%;
    }

    &--1-3 @{child}
    {
        width: 33.3%;
    }

    &--1-4 @{child}
    {
        width: 25.0%;
    }

    &--1-5 @{child}
    {
        width: 20.0%;
    }
}

// I might need to provide a child element

.data-table
{
    .build-on(size, table);
}

// I might not

.grid
{
    .build-on(size, "");
}
```

Comment: are you looking for something like default values?

Comment: I am looking for the output to be .grid--1-1 if no argument is passed. Right now its .grid--1-1 "" However, I do need to sometimes pass that an argument over. I just really don't want to create another mix-in for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass it like so:

```
.yourClass
{
    .build-on(size, ~'');
}
```

**Or Better Yet...**

Define a default: `.build-on(size, @child: ~'') { ... }` then no second is needed:

```
.yourClass
{
    .build-on(size);
}
```

Comment: Without the ~ it was writing out a space. Thanks again.